# Second time google mail prompt is not showing using angular

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I am using google mail prompt in angular 2 and currently using the angular2-social-login NPM. 
Here google mail prompt opening first time and second time its not opening the google mail login prompt.

```
 <button class="btn gmailBtn" (click)="signIn('google')" type="button">Login with Gmail</button>

 <button class="btn gmailBtn" (click)="logout()" type="button">Log OUT</button>


import { AuthService } from "angular2-social-login";

constructor(private _auth: AuthService) { }

 signIn(provider: any) {
    this.sub = this._auth.login(provider).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.user = data;
      }
    );
  }


  logout() {
    this._auth.logout().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.user = null;
      }
    )
  }
```

Google Gmail Not opening second time and showing older fetched data.